# Javascript Cookie define Path

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I am new to JavaScript and I'm kinda stuck.
I want to allow my cookie to work on all of my pages.
I know that I need to add "/" to path. The only problem is that the little script I got is a bit different than all the examples out there.

Does somebody know where to put it?

```
var expdate = new Date();
expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365));

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
  var thisCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expires) ? "; expires=" +
    expires.toGMTString() : "") + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") + ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") + ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
  document.cookie = thisCookie;

}

function showCookie() {
  alert(unescape(document.cookie));
}

function getCookieVal(offset) {
  var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
  if (endstr == -1) endstr = document.cookie.length;
  return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}

function GetCookie(name) {
  var arg = name + "=";
  var alen = arg.length;
  var clen = document.cookie.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < clen) {
    var j = i + alen;
    if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) return getCookieVal(j);
    i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
    if (i === 0) break;
  }
  return null;
}

function MyNamer() {
  var now = new Date();
  now.setTime(now.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var username = GetCookie("username");
  if ((!username) || (username == 'null')) {
    username = prompt("What is your name?:", "");
  }
  setCookie("username", username, now);
  if (username) {
    document.write(username);
    setCookie("username", username, now);

  } else
    document.write("Guest")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your code it looks like the 4th argument in `setCookie` is the one you want:

```
setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure)
```

e.g.`setCookie("myCookie", "myCookieValue", new Date(), "/")`

What are you using the cookie for? The webserver you're making the request from controls cookie data, including path. If you're just storing data then you could use the browsers' [local/session storage](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp) objects?

Comment: Thanks, 
I want to use it to remember the users' name. When the users enters the site a message pops up and asks for a name. This name is stored as a cookie but only if the users visits the home page (which is in the main directory). I'd like this to be availibe on all pages.